# Can't get text out of forloop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

i'm using Firebase cloud functions to count labels in a Firestore array of each document in a collection. The labels are tracked in another collection which increments by 1 every time a particular element is counted.

The array looks like: `aLabels:[tree, car, animal]` but sometimes is like this: `aLabels: "empty"` hence the `if` statement.

I've managed to locate the collection and loop through the documents but i don't know how, when looping, to get the loop label name(like `tree`, `car` or `animal`) and not the actual work `label`.

```
exports.imageLabelTracking = functions
  .region("europe-west1")
  .https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    const imagesCollection = await firestore.collection("images").get();
    const imageDocs = imagesCollection.docs;
    const trackingCollection = await firestore.collection("tracking");
    const trackingDocRef = trackingCollection.doc("aLabels");

    for (const image of imageDocs) {
      const imageDoc = image.data();

      const imageLabels = imageDoc.aLabels;

      if (imageLabels === "empty") {
        await trackingDocRef.update({
          empty: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1),
        });
      } else {
        for (const label of imageLabels) {
          console.log(label);
          await trackingDocRef.update({
            label: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1), //problem line here
          });
        }
      }
    }

    res.send("Hello");
  });
```

My data comes out like:
[image]

Instead of it coming out like:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `[]` to tell JavaScript to interpret `label` as a variable and use its value. So:

```
await trackingDocRef.update({
  [label]: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1),
});
```